# convert fields in a column into multiple columns

Tags: python, shell, awk

I have a file with several columns:

In column 13 (last column), the fields are seprated by ';'

```
Column 13
ExAC_AN_EAS=140;ExAC_AC_NFE=538;ExAC_AF_AFR=0.382; ExAC_AF_AMR=0.343
```

I need to scan column 13, find  fields that have ExAC_AF* and put the values in separate columns and the headers will be ExAC_AF*

The output that I would want looks like this:

```
column 1-13    ExAC_AF_AFR   ExAC_AF_AMR 
etc            0.382         0.343
```

I'm not really sure where to start so any guide in terms of workflow would be helpful. I have basic python and shell scripting.

Comment: Do you have access to either Excel or Google sheets? Whenever I need to do that kind of thing, I kind of cheat and use their "split text to columns" features (you can specify the delimiter to ";"). Like this: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6325535?hl=en

Comment: Please post a full sample of the file. You say **"In column 13 (last column), the fields are seprated by ';"** But if it is Col 13, what do Col 1 - 12 look like?

Comment: Since you want to print headers, you also need to know what `ExAC_AF*` will match, or you will have to read the entire file to find out first.